# Web scraping with urls changing by date

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing a script that uses *python* and *BeautifulSoup4*. The script itself is finished the only part that has brought up an issue is the urls being used.

I am passing the urls with this code:

```
urllist = ["samplewebsitename.com/2015/05/xxx-chapter-{}.html".format(str(pgnum).zfill(2)) for pgnum in range(1, chapter_number+1)]
for url in urllist:
    url_queue.put(url)
```

A problem that I have come across is when scraping a site I noticed that a part of the url is changing depending on when it was uploaded. For example:

```
samplewebsitename.com/2015/05/xxx-chapter-01.html
samplewebsitename.com/2015/06/xxx-chapter-32.html
samplewebsitename.com/2015/10/xxx-chapter-47.html
```

I can deal with the chapters because they are sequential but there is no set pattern for the months and years on when the material was added. I'm wondering if there is a way to figure this out.

The year and month would also need to become variables to be replaced by the hard coded ones in the example but getting them from the website seems a bit harder than I thought it would be.

**EDIT**
Apparently you can grab the links from a dropdown list which simplifies the whole problem to just parsing the dropdown itself for all the links.

[image]

The only minor issue that I am having now is how to actually parse it correctly. Currently trying to find the select element of the site but i'm still quite new at this.

```
#Gets all the url's for each chapter
urllist = []
starturl = "http://www.bimanga.com/2015/05/read-manga-tokyo-ghoul-re-chapter-01.html"
response = requests.get(starturl)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for option in soup.findAll('option'):
    #urllist.append(option["value"])
    print(option["value"]) #Debugging
```

Comment: You cannot figure that out unless you know the upload date of the books which you are interested in scraping. Or if you really need you can try brute force approach and check all possible dates but I really really discourage such way.

Comment: Are the chapters linked to one another? If so, once you locate one chapter, you can look for links to other chapters.

Comment: There isn't any explicit links but there is a dropdown list on the site, would it be possible to get them from there?

http://i.imgur.com/pvKgnDw.png

Answer (score 0):

The year and month can be gained from the dropdown you see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQV5y.png

Parse the dropdown (`select` element) and get the links. Then you probably won't even need to construct the url from year and month. The dropdown might contain entire url to the chapter.

Comment: Is there any examples that you know of or references on parsing a dropdown? Having a bit of trouble with it. This is what I have at the moment.
`#Gets all the url's for each chapter
urllist = []
starturl = "http://www.bimanga.com/2015/05/read-manga-tokyo-ghoul-re-chapter-01.html"
response = requests.get(starturl)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for option in soup.find_all('select', attrs={'name':'menu'}):
    #urllist.append(option["value"])
    sys.stdout.write(option["value"])

for url in urllist:
    url_queue.put(url)`

Comment: You need to select the "option" tag.

Comment: I've tries using option as the tag. `for option in soup.findAll('option'):` but it just keeps on giving an empty set. Could it be that beautifulsoup doesn't support working with drop-down lists? Or is the error on my part?